# Subquery SQL with Group By

Tags: sql

My goal is to get the `percent` by dividing strata/total, but I realize that my all my `total` values were the same, which was the first value after group by REF_YEAR, so every strata value was divided by the same value, leading to wrong percent. My code is below. I wonder what's wrong with the subquery. I'm running this on Jupyter Lab using R kernel.

```
SELECT
    REF_YEAR,
    STRATA_DESC_E,
    COUNT(*) AS strata,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df GROUP BY REF_YEAR) AS total,
    COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df GROUP BY REF_YEAR) AS percent
FROM 
    df
GROUP BY 
    REF_YEAR, STRATA_DESC_E
```

From this image, you can see that the total values are all the same

[image]

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, and also tell us which database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which database you are using, if it supports analytic functions, then here is a simple way to write your logic:

```
SELECT
    REF_YEAR,
    STRATA_DESC_E,
    COUNT(*) AS strata,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY REF_YEAR) AS total,
    100.0 * COUNT(*) / COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY REF_YEAR) AS percent
FROM df
GROUP BY
    REF_YEAR,
    STRATA_DESC_E;
```

If you are using something like MySQL 5.7 or another database which does not support analytic functions, we can try joining to a subquery which finds the per `REF_YEAR` aggregates:

```
SELECT
    t1.REF_YEAR,
    t1.STRATA_DESC_E,
    COUNT(*) AS strata,
    t2.cnt AS total,
    100.0 * COUNT(*) / t2.cnt AS percent
FROM df t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT REF_YEAR, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM df
    GROUP BY REF_YEAR
) t2
    ON t1.REF_YEAR = t2.REF_YEAR
GROUP BY
    t1.REF_YEAR,
    t1.STRATA_DESC_E;
```

Comment: Thanks! The second code works! May I know why do we need to use inner join?

Comment: The thing is, you are trying to access different aggregates, one by `REF_YEAR` alone and the other by both `REF_YEAR` and `STRATA_DESC_E`.  Without window functions, one way to do this is to just do two separate aggregations, hence the join I used.  I prefer the first version, though.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
REF_YEAR,
STRATA_DESC_E,
COUNT(*) AS strata,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df GROUP BY REF_YEAR) AS total,
COUNT(*)*100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(x.*) FROM df x where x.REF_YEAR = d.REF_YEAR ) AS percent
FROM df d
GROUP BY REF_YEAR, STRATA_DESC_E
```

Comment: I tried it on R using Jupyter Lab, but it returned "Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement): near "*": syntax error"

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions.  The correct formulation is:

```
SELECT REF_YEAR, STRATA_DESC_E,
       COUNT(*) AS strata,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY REF_YEAR) AS total,
       100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY REF_YEAR) AS percent
FROM df
GROUP BY REF_YEAR, STRATA_DESC_E;
```